# SQL Query to Combine Duplicates into New DE

Tags: query, journeybuilder, dataextensions, sql

I am having a hard time creating a query that takes duplicate leads located in the same Data Extension but are separated by the SW Tag field which breaks them into another row. I would like to combine matching leads into another Data Extension that would be used for sending.

Current output:

DE NAME: SW_Abandoned_Cart_DE

```
|Lead: Lead ID   |  Lead: Email           | SW Tag  |
|--------------  |  --------------------- | ------- |
|1               |  Al                    | Water   |
|1               |  Al                    | Soda    |
```

Desired output:

DE Name: SW_Abandoned_Cart_Send

```
|Lead: Lead ID | Lead: Email |  SW Tag       |
|------------- | ----------- |  ------------ |
|1             | Al          |  Water, Soda  |
```

Here is a query I found that is close to what I want to do but Query Studio is not reading the query correct.

```sql
SELECT
  [Lead: Lead ID]
, [Lead: Email]
, GROUP_CONCAT distinct [SW Tag] 
FROM SW_Abandoned_Cart_DE 
LEFT JOIN SW_Abandoned_Cart_Send ON SW_Abandoned_Cart_DE.[Lead: Lead ID] = SW_Abandoned_Cart_Send.[Lead: Lead ID] 
GROUP BY SW_Abandoned_Cart_DE.[Lead: Email]
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for providing the desired output and for giving the query a shot.

If you're building an abandoned cart email, I would *not* recommend this path.

Your send query could simply be a distinct list of leads:

```sql
SELECT top 1 with ties
  [Lead: Lead ID]
, [Lead: Email]
FROM SW_Abandoned_Cart_DE 
order by row_number() over (partition by [Lead: Lead ID] order by newid())
```

Then in your email, you could just do a [**lookup**](https://ampscript.guide/lookuporderedrows) and iterate over the rows in `SW_Abandoned_Cart_DE`.  This is much easier than a query to concatenate them into a single field.  Plus you'd need additional scripting in the email to unfurl the comma-separated data before you can use it.

If I haven't convinced you to look at it differently, here's how to unpivot:

```sql
select 
  c.[Lead: Lead ID]
, c.[Lead: Email]
, x.tags [SW Tag]
from SW_Abandoned_Cart_DE c
cross apply (
  select 
    c0.[SW Tag] + ','
  from SW_Abandoned_Cart_DE c0
  where c0.[Lead: Lead ID] = c.[Lead: Lead ID] 
  for xml path('') 
) x (tags)
```

(I didn't test this query, but it should work in SFMC)